# gitolite http mode repo can't work successful

Tags: gitolite

I have install gitolite and set it successful with http mode.Then,I modify the gitolite.conf,[image]

But the repo C can't be used.
[image]

who cant help me?

Comment: In http, it is called `C.git`, not `C`.

Answer (score 0):

`C` or `C.git` is fine.

But `admin` will only work if you are sure the [Apache server has correctly authenticated admin](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html) and is calling gitolite.

If Apache is trying to directly server `git/C`, it would not find it (since only gitolite knows to trasnlate that into `~git/repositories/C.git`)

To check if gitolite is called, look for gitolite logs in `~git/.gitolite/logs`.

Comment: 2016-02-05.15:27:00     14332   http    ARGV=admin      SOC=git-upload-pack 'C' FROM=116.236.254.134
2016-02-05.15:27:00     14332   pre_git C       admin   R       any     refs/.*
2016-02-05.15:27:00     14332           system,git,http-backend
2016-02-05.15:27:00     14332   END

Comment: the log content shows above, I don't kown what 's the mean

Comment: @S.Yuan it looks good. Now do you have `~git/repositories/C.git` on your gitolite server?

Comment: yes, but in _projects.list_ file . there are no C.git

Comment: If I  modify _RW+  =  admin_ to  _RW+  = @all_ . then the _C repo_ can work regularly

Comment: @all means anonymous access. Forllowing http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#making-repositories-available-to-both-ssh-and-http-mode-clientsn, what does a `curl http://admin:password@server/git/info` return? (replace `password` and `server` with the right values)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://gitolite.com/gitolite/http.html

> Finally, add an R = daemon access rule to all repositories you want to make available via http.

taken from http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html

Comment: perhaps info from http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitweb-daemon.html is usefull, too.